# web scraping returns an empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 result = requests.get('https://www.indeed.com/?vjk=5bc59746be36d8d0')
 source = result.content
 soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

 job_titles = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "jcs-JobTitle"})

 print(job_titles)
```

The problem here that printing job_titles returns an empty list instead of the job titles in the web site

please help me fix this problem and any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I first went to the URL you're requesting, I was shown a search page with no jobs listed. It was only after I submitted a search that the page was populated with results. When I returned to the original URL again, the page was still populated (possibly with cached results). The blank page is probably what you're getting back when you get the page from `requests`.

Try using the full URL with parameters that the browser forwards you to after a search. For example, the URL `https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%20engineer&l=Raleigh%2C%20NC&vjk=b971ec43674ab50e` gives me back 15 job title links.